# I want to display default profile image if user do not have profile image

Tags: php

I am trying to display a default image if user do not have profile image
but I am not getting what to do next so.. can any write further code
as I tried this code but not working ... thank you in advance

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['uid'])){$uidval=$_SESSION['uid'];

      $getImage=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT user_avatar FROM user where 
      uid=".$uidval) or die("Could not retrieve image: " 
      .mysqli_error($db));
       $path=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getImage) or die("Could not fetch array : " 
       .mysqli_error($db));

       }


      if((isset($_GET['user_avatar']))&&(!empty($_GET['user_avatar']))){

      $user_avatar = $_GET['user_avatar'];  
              }
```

HTML code

```
 <div class="profile-image">
   <img src="<?php echo 'userfiles/avatars/'.$path['user_avatar'];?>" />
 </div>
```

Comment: you can set condition like `if(!empty($path)){
  $path=$image; } else { $path = 'defaultImage.png'; } ` then in html you can define this like `<img src="images/<?php echo $path; ?>" />`

Comment: `file_exists("full path with image name")` will check whether file exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add whole PHP code with if and else part. Your question is half! Still let me try if I could answer your question.

For Default image, you should add a image to your upload folder and when you check if profile images is empty or not, in else part, you should add that default static path.

Completing your above question my answer is as below:

```
if(!empty($path)){
  $path='<img src="/image/'.$image.'"/>';
} else {
  $path='<img src="/image/default.jpg"/>';
}
```

Comment: i tried till there later i did not get what to do so

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: Can you please add your all code here? and also make sure that default images is there on your path at your image folder.

Comment: Try:
if(!empty($path['user_avatar'])){
  $path='<img src="/userfiles/avatars/'.$image.'"/>';
} else {
  $path='<img src="/userfiles/avatars/default.jpg"/>';
}

Also confirm the you have the default image in avatars folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>

  @if($user)
  <img src="{{ $user['user_avatar'] ? $user['user_avatar']:'default_profile_image' }}" alt="user image">

  @else
  <img src="default_profile_image" alt="user image">
  @endif

</div>
```

I would advise you to query the database and send the whole user object (that contains the property holding the user image) to you your rendering template and have this logic there.